# Ionic 2 image capture in different folder upload with 1 hit

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, camera, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am creating an App where I want to capture different image on different folder and there are some data in the form too. So I want to upload all in single API Hit. I am facing following issue:-
1. How I can capture different image in different folder (folder is fixed)
2. How to send with that api. 
My Required image is as following [image]

I tried with

```
    pickPicture(){
  Camera.getPicture({
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType     : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE
  }).then((imageData) => {
    // imageData is a base64 encoded string
      this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
  }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
  });
}
```

But here I am not able to show different images in different folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hint . You should put any id on `pickPicture(){}` like `pickPicture('img1'){}`on click on button and then pass that id to match the name and same with different id.

```
public pickPicture(myurl) {
    //console.log("inside take picture "+myurl);
     Camera.getPicture({({
       destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  sourceType     : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }).then(imageData => {
      console.log(myurl);
      if(myurl=="Image1"){
        this.Image1 = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
      }else if(myurl=="Image2"){
        this.Image2 = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
      }});
```